# I am new to scss, getting issue in the scss code format

Tags: css, sass, less

Hey I am new to scss I am getting some error in my code. I am using a parent class for my page.  This is my css

```
.d-layout {


    .bg-img {
        height: 304px;
        width: 1140px;
    }

    .p-color: {
        color: #A50034;
    }
    .ptd {
        .icon {
            height: 8px;
            width: 8px;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
        }
        button {
            color: #A50034;
            font-family: "LG Smart_Global";
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 28px;
        }
    }

}
```

And the error is `SassError: Invalid CSS after "    };": expected "}", was ".p-color: {"`

Comment: there is no problem in this code

Comment: did you update your question with the answer? as dgknca said there is no issue with the code you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue with your sass code is the colon after ".p-color"

Code should be:

```
.p-color {
    color: #A50034;
}
```